# How to implement online/offline sync in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Am doing mobile application using ionic framework,
Having mysql db in server & using api to process get & post methods( response will be in JSON format) 
How to implement online & offline data sync in my app.
It should work like below

```
- Need internet connection for first time login. so that it can pull data from server
- If user wents to offline, he should able to view, add in offline
- Once he goes to online again, the data should sync in server
```

Answer (score 1):

In an article published 1 year ago by Marco Fernandes, using Ionic 1.x. It's possible to create a kind of "4-way data binding".

It should be easy to implement something like this in Ionic 2.

http://frontmag.no/artikler/utvikling/offline-data-synchronization-ionic